# mysql trigger AFTER INSERT if condition syntax error

Tags: mysql

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 7

```
DELIMITER //
  CREATE TRIGGER after_tableA_insert AFTER INSERT ON tableA
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `triedTime`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 60000) THEN
       INSERT into error
       SET triedTime = NEW.changedat;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 60K hours is a long time??

Answer (score 2):

Based on your own answer, the issue appears to have been with this line:

```
IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `triedTime`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 60000) THEN
```

The problem is the `` `triedTime` `` reference. According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> Within the trigger body, the `OLD` and `NEW` keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger.

That is to say, without either `NEW` or `OLD` you cannot access columns of the affected rows. So, in the above shown line you probably want to use the `NEW` keyword:

```
IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NEW.`triedTime`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) < 60000) THEN
```

Your own method of looking the value up in the table works as well, only it means an extra table hit, which may affect performance.

Comment: +1 for this. If you want to use a variable, you could use for example:  `varA = TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NEW.triedTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())`

Answer (score 1):

I done with it!

```
    CREATE TRIGGER `after_tableA_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tableA`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    declare curSdate integer;
    set curSdate = (SELECT 
    IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`triedTime`,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())<1,1,0) as 
    res from tableA  where trialId = NEW.trialId);
    IF curSdate = 1 THEN
    INSERT into error SET errorNumber = NEW.trialId
           , userId = NEW.userId, changedat = NEW.triedTime;
    ELSEIF curSdate = 0 THEN
           INSERT into error_logs SET  errorNumber = 0, userId = 0;
       END IF;
   END
```

Comment: The `set curSdate = (SELECT ...)` will fail if `trialid` is not unique. See AndriyM's answer for identifying the cause of the problem.

Comment: Within 1 second?

Comment: yes, In above case trailId is primary key